# Install4j "Browse" Button hanging the installer

Tags: install4j

I'm using `install4j 6.0.3`, everything works exactly like it should, however if the user tries to change the installation location by using the "`Browse`" button, the installer locks up completely, and you need to use task manager to kill the process.

This happens on `Windows 7` & `Windows 8(.1)`

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this issue?

Comment: This is the first report of that kind and I cannot reproduce it. What JRE do you use? Can you try with a different JRE bundle? If it persists, please use jstack to get a thread dump while it hangs.

Comment: @IngoKegel, thanks for the help! I posted an answer below which seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is extremely weird, as I was debugging according to Ingo, I checked the option "`Allow new folder creation`" on, made a build, then checked it off again and made another build.

That build now works for the affected users, I guess there was a latent weird option in the config file or something.